# Avoid user delete some file on Dropbox

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I use Dropbox core-api and I need create .txt file to recode some important info. I hope this .txt file can been hide or keep to avoid user delete it!

And I find datastore-api's table may match my demand, but its lib are not same as core-api!

So, is it can be implemented on Core-api or can I use Core-api to control Dropbox datastore?

Comment: just make the file read-only

Comment: refer to https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/devguide#app-permissions

Comment: @RachelGallen My APP will use user storage ,so user = owner!
not to share link , can it work?

Comment: the dropbox guide also shows how to hide folders. put it in a folder of it's own and hide the folder

Comment: ok,I will search it ,Thank :)

Comment: I try it !
It's can hide on APK ,but it can not hide in web version!

Comment: well at least that's a start!

Comment: The user has full read/write access to all of the data in the user's Dropbox account, regardless of how it is added, so it's not currently possible to prevent the user from deleting something in their own account.

Comment: Yap, so I decide to change my APP model!